# The soft part inside a fruit's stone/pit

Tags: word-request

What do you call the soft part inside a fruit's stone/pit? For instance, when you break an apricot's stone/pit you can see a soft and tasty piece that's edible.

I would also like to know which word is more common **a stone** or **a pit** of a fruit.

Comment: There seems to be a fair amount of literature on the subject, many sites promote its goodness and claim it defeats cancer.... this page seemed to me the most level headed. I would limit the intake, apart from possible death (hard to ignore), the side-effects of consuming amygdalin  are pretty nasty https://www.drweil.com/health-wellness/body-mind-spirit/cancer/apricot-kernels-a-natural-cancer-treatment/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the **[kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apricot_kernel)**. I'm not sure about "edible" (since it contains amygadalin, that produces cyanide). It could also called the seed, which would be the proper biological term, although there may be some confusion (Non-biologists might consider the whole pit to be a seed. The technical terminology doesn't quite match everyday speech)

Stone and pit are both possible. Stone is more frequent in British English, pit may be more common in American. Pip can be used for smaller seeds, such as in apples or oranges.

Comment: I eat them. I hope I won't die.

Comment: Death seems to be unlikely, if you are treated promptly. Convulsions and coma, on the other hand...https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20196932

Comment: @SovereignSun You really shouldn't.

Comment: I also tried kernels of other fruit

Comment: @1006a in that article about cyanide poisoning linked in above comment, they refer to it as a *seed*, is that contradicting *kernel* or does it mean something else?

Comment: It depends on the fruit. Almonds (which are practically a peach with no flesh) are obviously fine, but some are much more dangerous. There was a story in the UK press recently where a man almost died after eating the inside of cherry stones http://metro.co.uk/2017/07/27/father-of-three-almost-died-from-cyanide-poisoning-after-eating-cherry-stones-6810221/

Comment: @dlatikay Article edited to address "seed". Commenters: Please use chat if you want to discuss the toxicity of prunus sp. seeds.

Comment: @SovereignSun If you eat one or two, every now and then, as an otherwise healthy adult, then you shouldn't experience any adverse affects.  Apple seeds contain cyanide (or perhaps as suggested in this answer a cyanide precursor, I don't know), but you need to eat the seeds from about 20 apples to reach a fatal dose, which is unlikely unless you're really trying.  A quick search indicates you would need to eat about 8-10 peach seeds for similar exposure.  I don't know how quickly your body processes it, so it may build up if you're eating 1 or 2 daily.

Answer (score 6):

As shown by this paragraph, an acceptable word for the soft inside part would be *kernel*.  **stone** and **pit** would both refer to the outer shell with what's inside it.

> The European Food Safety Authority (EFSA) warned that a single serving
>   of three small apricot **kernels** or one large apricot **kernel** could put
>   adults over the suggested safe levels of cyanide exposure, while one
>   small **kernel** could be toxic to a toddler. The EFSA advise that no more
>   than 20 micrograms of cyanide per kilogram of body weight should be
>   consumed at one time. This limits consumption to one **kernel** for
>   adults. Even half a **kernel** would be over the limit for children.

http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/314337.php